# Ipad/iPhone fonts not rendering properly

Tags: iphone, css, ipad, fonts

I have an issue with fonts on my iPad (4) / iOs 7.0b4.

I have this CSS:

```
 p span {
        font-family: 'Arial Black', sans-serif;
        font-size: 22px;
    }
```

Renders fine in all browsers but not on iPhone or iPad. It displays a serif font and not Arial Black. Even if I write "Sans-Serif" it displays a serif font.

Changing to ArialMT, Arial or Helvetiva doesn't work either.

I use the Foundation 4 framework with an own stylesheet.

Do I miss something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iOS does not support Arial Black.

Source: http://iosfonts.com/

**EDIT:** Seems that the problem was that the CSS rule wasn't overwriting the foundation CSS. Adding !important fixed the issue so if you will write a more specific CSS rule it will work.

Comment: yeah, but even when I enter "Arial" it doesn't render at all.

Comment: try to declare helvetica for iOS

Comment: nope doesn't work. I use foundation 4 as a framework. Is that maybe causing the errors?

Comment: @Marek123 Try to add !important just to check if you are actually overwriting the foundation code

Comment: Yes, the !important helped!

Comment: @Marek123 Cool, you probably need to write a more specific CSS rule to overwrite the foundation code. Try to add some more selectors and it should work!